# Passing parameters to stored procedure using pandas.read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, stored-procedures

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters to a stored procedure when using read_sql_query?

This works fine:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("EXEC x_tntLog_list_bySerialNo @SerialNo='B201209-058'", cnxn)
```

But when I try to loop it with multiple parameters:

```
params = ["B201209-058", "B201209-059", "B201209-060"]
for param in params
    query = "EXEC x_tntLog_list_bySerialNo @SerialNo=?", param
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
    results = results.append(df, ignore_index=True)
results
```

I get the this error:

```
Execution failed on sql '('EXEC x_tntLog_list_bySerialNo @SerialNo=?', ['B201209-060'])': The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

which I'm assuming is because `read_sql_query` looking for the `cnxn` object for the first argument.

**EDIT**

I realize that `params` is a list of strings but that did not seem to be an issue in a previous version of this code that I was able to get to work:

```
params = ["B201209-058", "B201209-059", "B201209-060"]
for param in params:
     cursor.execute("EXEC x_tntLog_list_bySerialNo @SerialNo=?", param)
     for row in cursor.fetchall():
         sheet.append([value for value in row])
wb.save('Output.xlsx')
```

some may wonder why I am not using this code given that it works and the reason is that I would like to manipulate the data using pandas rather than excel

Answer (score 0):

I feel a little embarrassed but the solution was pretty simple:

`query = "EXEC x_tntLog_list_bySerialNo @SerialNo=" + "'" + param + "'"`

concatenating the SQL string took care of it.

[obviously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVaRc.gif)

Comment: This could lead to Sql Injection.